# Find CorelDraw Web links

Tags: vba, url, hyperlink, coreldraw

Does anyone know how to get the Web links in a CorelDraw document?  I am using CorelDraw 13 X3 on Windows, and it comes with a Link manager and VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following will get the address of a shape.

```
Dim s As Shape
  For Each s In ActiveDocument.ActivePage.Shapes
   s.URL.Address ....
  Next s
End Sub
```